# BigQuery-Java: difference between QueryResponse and GetQueryResultsResponse

Tags: google-bigquery

In [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart) provided by Google, 2 classes are used to fetch results. QueryResponse and GetQueryResultsResponse. 
I am not able to understand purpose of these 2 classes and do we have to use these 2 classes?
We are getting data from both: queryResponse.getRows() and queryResults.getRows()

I have gone through [docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/) but could not figure out. what is the difference between these 2 classes and which is better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two results are virtually identical (in fact, they are identical in the raw HTTP request). The difference is how you get them.

QueryResponse is returned by jobs.query(). This method can be used to run a query, but has only limited configuration options. It is intended as a convenience function. For more query options (such as setting a destination table, allowing large results, etc), use jobs.insert().  Another limitation of jobs.query() is that it may time out before the query has completed. Partly, this is because many clients (such as in AppEngine) require all HTTP requests to finish within 30 seconds or so. If jobs.query() times out, it will still report a job id that can be used to fetch the results with jobs.get_query_results().

GetQueryResultsResponse is returned by jobs.get_query_results(). This can be used to get the results of a query started by either jobs.query() or jobs.insert(). Query results (if you don't specify a destination table) are available for 24 hours after the query completes. jobs.get_query_results() allows you to fetch these results at any time. jobs.query() only gives you the query results once.

There is a further difference between the two, which is that jobs.query() just returns the first page of results. jobs.get_query_results() can be used to get multiple pages of results.

Hopefully this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. So if I understood correctly, jobs().getQueryResults(..) is only fetching the results and not executing the query. So if I want to execute a query I will have to  use jobs().query(..).

Comment: Then one more question is, suppose I want to get information: TotalBytesProcessed, TotalRows, is cahceHit.. should I use "QueryResponse" or "GetQueryResultsResponse"? Or it doesn't matter and both will give same values?

Comment: Yes, that's right... getQueryResults doesn't execute the query. Both query() and getQueryResults() return the total rows, but only query() returns the number of bytes processed (you can also get that information from jobs.get()).